# Action function not getting called

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to create new contact records by clicking on create new contact button specified for each account record and on clicking of it a popup should come that should display the required fields for creating a contact record and on clicking of save a contact record has to be created and it should be attached to that particular account. Here I am not able to create a contact record at all. Can anyone please solve this.

Controller side:

```
    public Contact objAcc {get;set;}    
    public string strAccId {get;set;}

   public void accActionMethodInController()
    {       
        system.debug('strAccId     ======1======> ' +strAccId);
        if(strAccId!='' && strAccId!= NULL)
        {
            system.debug('strAccId     ======1======> ' +strAccId);
            objAcc = new Contact();
            system.debug('objAcc       ======1======>'  +objAcc);
            objAcc.AccountId = strAccId;
            system.debug('objAcc.AccountId  ======1======>'  +objAcc.AccountId);
        }
    }

    public void createContact()
    {
        insert objAcc;
    }
```

Page:

```
        <apex:outputPanel id="popup">
            <div id="selectColumnPopup" style="display:none;">
                <div class="popupBackground" layout="block" />
                <div class="popupForeground" style="height:40%; width:43%;" > 
                    First Name: <apex:inputField value="{!objAcc.FirstName}" /><br />
                    Last Name: <apex:inputField value="{!objAcc.LastName}" /><br />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!createContact}" />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" onClick="closePopUp()"/>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel id="acc1" layout="none" rendered="{!accountList.size!=0}">
            <apex:repeat id="repeatAccount" value="{!accountList}" var="item">  
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataCell"><Input type="button" value="Create New Contact" onclick="displayPopUp('{!item.oAccount.Id}')"/></td>
                </tr>   
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:outputPanel>             
    </apex:form>

    <script>

        function displayPopUp(accountId)
        {
            alert('here : '+accountId);
            accActionMethod(accountId);
            document.getElementById('selectColumnPopup').style.display = 'block';
        }

        function closePopUp()
        {
            document.getElementById('selectColumnPopup').style.display = 'None';
        }               

    </script>
 </apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is (most) probably happening because your `objAcc` is `null` the moment you try to insert it. In your Salesforce page you call `accActionMethod(accountId)`, but I don't see this method in your controller. Instead, you have `accActionMethodInController()` method there without parameters.

Also, your `strAccId` is never being set to any value(at least I didn't see it in the code you provided), so you will never get into that `if` block.